# Unexpected Mysqli WHERE is not null Value Returned

Tags: php, mysqli, notnull

Mysqli query to a table containing rows of data.

When i use this `SELECT` it returns no rows when a row does exist with the desired request.

I have written this several ways of which i have seen on various references but all return no rows.

I wish to retrieve`(SELECT)` the latest`(DESC)(LIMIT 1)` row by`(datetime_upload)` in full`(*)` WHERE `(licensePath)` has something in the cell`(IS NOT NULL)`.

**Q.** I would like to know what i need to adjust in my select statement to return the desired result?

[image: MySQL Table]

**The Select:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM driver_docs WHERE driver_profileId LIKE '$uid' AND WHERE licensePath IS NOT NULL ORDER BY datetime_upload DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if ($row) { 
        if ($row["licensePath"]) {
            echo "license";
        } 
    }
    else {
        echo "NO ROWS";
    }
```

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()` and you'll see the syntax error.

Comment: What is being passed for `LIKE '$uid'`? You may want to do `WHERE driver_profileId = '$uid'` instead. LIKE may not be returning what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you get results when you remove the WHERE completely?

Comment: the error returns as expected: ` 'WHERE licensePath IS NOT NULL ORDER BY datetime_upload DESC LIMIT 1' `

Comment: I assume licensepath is text or var char, however null and "" are both different values. Try licenspath != ""

Comment: When i remove the later where it works correctly with the LIKE. I have tried replacing like with = and with the second WHERE continues to error.

Comment: Try `$query = "SELECT * FROM driver_docs WHERE  licensePath IS NOT NULL AND driver_profileId LIKE '$uid'  ORDER BY datetime_upload DESC LIMIT 1";` @StuartWickenden

Comment: @MikeM. The cell is `VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: @StuartWickenden - that's because you only need one WHERE: ` WHERE driver_profileId LIKE '$uid' AND licensePath IS NOT NULL`. Two WHEREs will give you a syntax error

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Allright still try what I said the `WHERE licensePath != "" AND ....` as said 2x where probably gives you the issue, what does the dbms like phpmyadmin say?

Comment: @MikeM. Spot on. That's clarified soemthing for me which i never knew! Thanks. Answer the question for tick and upvote. Thanks Mike!

`$query = "SELECT * FROM driver_docs WHERE licensePath !='' AND driver_profileId LIKE '$uid' ORDER BY datetime_upload DESC LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null value and empty value is not the same.
As your cell is var_char your text would automatically be shown as an empty value.
Which would mean you do != '' instead of IS NOT NULL.

Most likely a NULL value is typed out as NULL.

-written on a phone in the bus on my way home.
Excuse me for grammatical errors and/or unfinished answering.

Answer (score 1):

$query = "SELECT * FROM driver_docs WHERE driver_profileId LIKE '$uid' AND WHERE licensePath IS NOT NULL ORDER BY datetime_upload DESC LIMIT 1";

you have used 2 where clause. Just remove second "Where" clause and add both condition with "And" Operator. It should work.

Comment: `WHERE driver_profileId LIKE '$uid' AND licensePath IS NOT NULL ORDER BY datetime_upload DESC LIMIT 1";`